# Long-running tasks with async server

Tags: python, websocket, tornado, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I think everyone knows what to do with long-running tasks in django: use celery and relax. But what if I want to get benefits of the websockets with aiohttp (or tornado)?

Let's say I have very CPU bound task which can take from a couple of seconds till multiple (5-10) minutes. It looks like pretty good idea to handle this task in websocket loop and notify user about the progress. No ajax requests, very fast response for short tasks.

```
async def websocket_handler(request):
    ws = web.WebSocketResponse()
    await ws.prepare(request)

    async for msg in ws:
        if msg.tp == aiohttp.MsgType.text:     
            answer_to_the_ultimate_question_of_life_the_universe_and_everything =\
                long_running_task(msg.data, NotificationHelper(ws))
            ws.send_str(json.dumps({
                'action': 'got-answer',
                'data': answer_to_the_ultimate_question_of_life_the_universe_and_everything,
            }))
    return ws
```

But on the other hand, CPU-bound task served in such way blocks entire thread as I understand. If I have 10 workers and 11 clients who wants to use application, 11th client won't be served until the 1st client's task is done.

Maybe, I should run tasks *which look big* in celery and tasks *which look small* in the main loop?

So, my question: is there any good design pattern for serving long-running tasks with async server?

Thanks!

Comment: `asyncio` won't help you with CPU-bound tasks.

Comment: @dirn is it good only for IO-bound tasks and different kind of interaction with server?

Comment: Well asyncio can help, it's livelier if task is hosted in a separate thread (or green thread with yields or subprocess for truly kinky). Obv., there are concerns -- what is ws connection dies? Can there be a data race? What about "truly more requests than resources" -- 503/queue/block/error?

Comment: if the function is picklable, how about using [`asyncio.run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.BaseEventLoop.run_in_executor)?

Comment: @shongololo I want to put ws object into function as it is shown in example. So, it looks like it is not pickable, is it?

Comment: @dmitry probably not, though is there maybe a way around passing the ws object into the function? (I am not familiar with NotificationHelper)

Comment: @shongololo NotificationHelper is just self-written class, wrapper for websocket. The base idea was to notify user about task progress. Now I see that it'll be better to put task into a queue (celery, redis) and push progress messages back into that queue. Client connects to this queue with websocket and listens to it. So websocket thread won't be blocked as queue should be listened in async manner.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just run your long-running CPU-bound task by `loop.run_in_executor()` and send progress notifications by `loop.call_soon_threadsafe()`.

If your job is not CPU but IO bound (sending emails for example) you may create a new task by `loop.create_task()` call. It looks like spawning new thread.

If you cannot use fire-and-forget approach you need to use persistent message broker like RabbitMQ (there is https://github.com/benjamin-hodgson/asynqp library for communicating with Rabbit in asyncio way).