# Python and Starlette: running a long async task

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, starlette

I have a simple experiment in the code snippet shown below.  My goal is to have the browser client (via a WebSocket) kick off a long-running task on the server, but the server should service WebSocket messages from the client while the long-running task is running.  Here's the workflow ("OK" means this step is working as-is in the snippet, while "?" means this is what I'm trying to figure out)...

- OK - Run the code
- OK - Launch a browser at 127.0.0.1
- OK - WebSocket connects
- OK - Click "Send" and the browser client generates a random number, sends it to the server, and the server echoes back the number
- OK - Click "Begin" and this invokes a long-running task on the server (5.0 seconds)
- ? - During this 5sec (while the long-running task is running), I'd like to click "Send" and have the server immediately echo back the random number that was sent from the client while the long-running task continues to be concurrently executed in the event loop

For that last bullet point, it is not working that way: rather, if you click "Send" while the long process is running, the long process finishes and *then* the numbers are echoed back.  To me, this demonstrates that `await simulate_long_process(websocket)` is truly waiting for `simulate_long_process()` to complete -- makes sense.  However, part of me was expecting that `await simulate_long_process(websocket)` would signal the event loop that it could go work on other tasks and therefore go back to the `while True` loop to service the next incoming messages.  I was expecting this because `simulate_long_process()` is fully async (`async def`, `await websocket.send_text()`, and `await asyncio.sleep()`).  The current behavior kinda makes sense but not what I want.  So my question is, how can I achieve my goal of responding to incoming messages on the WebSocket while the long-running task is running?  I am interested in two (or more) approaches:

1. Spawning the long-running task in a different thread.  For example, with `asyncio.to_thread()` or by stuffing a message into a separate queue that another thread is reading, which then executes the long-running task (e.g. like a producer/consumer queue).  Furthermore, I can see how using those same queues, at the end of the long-running tasks, I could then send acknowledgment messages back to the Starlette/async thread and then back to the client over the WebSocket to tell them a task has completed.
2. Somehow achieving this "purely async"?  "Purely async" means mostly or entirely using features/methods from the `asyncio` package.  This might delve into synchronous or blocking code, but here I'm thinking about things like: organizing my coroutines into a `TaskGroup()` object to get concurrent execution, using `call_soon()`, using `run_in_executor()`, etc.  I'm really interested in hearing about this approach!  But I'm skeptical since it may be convoluted.  The spirit of this is mentioned here: [Long-running tasks with async server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35355849/long-running-tasks-with-async-server)

I can certainly see the path to completion on approach (1).  So I'm debating how "pure async" I try to go -- maybe Starlette (running in its own thread) is the only async portion of my entire app, and the rest of my (CPU-bound, blocking) app is on a different (synchronous) thread.  Then, the Starlette async thread and the CPU-bound sync thread simply coordinate via a queue.  This is where I'm headed but I'd like to hear some thoughts to see if a "pure async" approach could be reasonably implemented.  Stated differently, if someone could refactor the code snippet below to work as intended (responding immediately to "Send" while the long-running task is running), using only or mostly methods from `asyncio` then that would be a good demonstration.

```
from starlette.applications import Starlette
from starlette.responses import HTMLResponse
from starlette.routing import Route, WebSocketRoute
import uvicorn
import asyncio

index_str = """<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
    const websocket = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:80");
    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
        websocket.onmessage = ({ data }) => {
            console.log('Received: ' + data)
            document.body.innerHTML += data + "<br>";
        };
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    WebSocket Async Experiment<br>
    <button onclick="websocket.send(Math.floor(Math.random()*10))">Send</button><br>
    <button onclick="websocket.send('begin')">Begin</button><br>
    <button onclick="websocket.send('close')">Close</button><br>
</body>
</html>
"""

def homepage(request):
    return HTMLResponse(index_str)


async def simulate_long_process(websocket):
    await websocket.send_text(f'Running long process...')
    await asyncio.sleep(5.0)


async def websocket_endpoint(websocket):
    await websocket.accept()
    await websocket.send_text(f'Server connected')
    while True:
        msg = await websocket.receive_text()
        print(f'server received: {msg}')
        if msg == 'begin':
            await simulate_long_process(websocket)
        elif msg == 'close':
            await websocket.send_text('Server closed')
            break
        else:
            await websocket.send_text(f'Server received {msg} from client')
    await websocket.close()
    print('Server closed')


if __name__ == '__main__':

    routes = [
        Route('/', homepage),
        WebSocketRoute('/', websocket_endpoint) ]

    app = Starlette(debug=True, routes=routes)
    uvicorn.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=80)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First:

> However, part of me was expecting that await simulate_long_process(websocket) would signal the event loop that it could go work on other tasks

That is **exactly** what `await` means: it means, "stop executing this coroutine (`websocket_endpoint`) while we wait for a result from `simulate_long_process`, and go service other coroutines".

As it happens, you don't have any concurrent coroutines running, so this just pauses things until `simulate_long_process` returns.

Second:

Even if you were to run `simulate_long_process` concurrently (e.g., by creating a task using `asyncio.create_task` and then checking if its complete), your `while` loop blocks waiting for text from the client. This means that you can't, for instance, send the client a message when `simulate_long_process` completes, because the client needs to send *you* something before the body of the `while` loop can execute.

---

I haven't worked with Starlette before, so this may not be the most canonical solution, but here's an implementation that uses a [`WebSocketEndpoint`](https://www.starlette.io/endpoints/#websocketendpoint) to implement the desired behavior:

```
from starlette.applications import Starlette
from starlette.responses import HTMLResponse
from starlette.routing import Route, WebSocketRoute
from starlette.endpoints import WebSocketEndpoint
import uvicorn
import asyncio

SERVER_PORT=8000

index_str = """<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
    const websocket = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:%s");
    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
        websocket.onmessage = ({ data }) => {
            console.log('Received: ' + data)
            document.body.innerHTML += data + "<br>";
        };
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    WebSocket Async Experiment<br>
    <button onclick="websocket.send(Math.floor(Math.random()*10))">Send</button><br>
    <button onclick="websocket.send('begin')">Begin</button><br>
    <button onclick="websocket.send('close')">Close</button><br>
</body>
</html>
""" % (SERVER_PORT)

def homepage(request):
    return HTMLResponse(index_str)

class Consumer(WebSocketEndpoint):
    encoding = 'text'
    task = None

    async def  on_connect(self, ws):
        await ws.accept()

    async def on_receive(self, ws, data):
        match data:
            case 'begin':
                if self.task is not None:
                    await ws.send_text('background task is already running')
                    return

                await ws.send_text('start background task')
                self.task = asyncio.create_task(self.simulate_long_task(ws))
            case 'close':
                await ws.send_text('closing connection')
                await ws.close()
            case _:
                await ws.send_text(f'Server received {data} from client')

    async def simulate_long_task(self, ws):
        await ws.send_text('start long process')
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        await ws.send_text('finish long process')
        self.task = None

    async def on_disconnect(self, ws, close_code):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':

    routes = [
        Route('/', homepage),
        WebSocketRoute('/', Consumer) ]

    app = Starlette(debug=True, routes=routes)
    uvicorn.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=SERVER_PORT)
```

(Note that this by default uses port `8000` instead of port `80` because I already have something running on port `80` locally.)

Comment: Thank you!  Perfect...your code is a great launching point and demo of how to use a pure async paradigm for this example and for my application as a whole.  Now I just need to decide how much I'm going to adopt async across my entire app.  My hesitation is that in my real app, I will have some truly CPU-bound tasks that I may not be able to refactor as async.   This is where I would maybe need to consider `to_thread()`,  `run_in_executor()`, or other methods.  It could get convoluted when compared to a two-threaded app...

Comment: ...the two-threaded app being one thread running async Starlette and the other thread running synchronous processes, and they communicate via a Queue.  Something I'll need to decide on.  I could experiment with your snippet by changing `asyncio.sleep(5)` to the synchronous `time.sleep(5)`

Comment: You could also consider hosting your long running task in a completely separate process and using a message queue to communicate between the web application and the task manager ([Celery](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/getting-started/introduction.html) is the canonical Python example of this sort of thing, but there are a variety of other solutions).